# transparent overlay over div with directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to add transparent overlay for a div that has my directive?

```
<img src="img.jpg" id="myId_a" my-directive>
<p id="myIdText" my-directive> text here </p>
```

I've tried something like that in  the directive:

```
$("<div></div>").css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "100%",
                "top": 0,
                "left": 0,
                "background-color": 'rgb(122,0,0)',
                "opacity": 0.5
            }).appendTo($element.css("position", "relative"));
```

This works fine for `<p>` element but fails for `<img>`.

Comment: Of course, you can't add a `div` to an `img` ... and to have an overlay for an `img`, the `position: relative` needs to be set to the image's parent

Comment: How can you append a **div** element into a `p` element (Invalid HTML), and even worse - To an `img` element?

Comment: And you use a template for a directives, you don't append it via jQuery

Comment: So basically it's not possible to make it from directly from a directive added for <img> tag?

Comment: Hi whats the purpose of the overlaying div? If you could post a fiddle it would be great. You can always have an overlaying div which covers both your image and p tag in your html page by setting its position to absolute.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0sdrw7h/1/   Is it right way to do that?
I've managed to overlay the element but i had to place it in separate tag. What i wanted to achieve is add overlay through a directive right to the element i add the directive for, not using a parent div.

Comment: @standy Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/b0sdrw7h/2/

Comment: You can also replace the directive element: https://jsfiddle.net/b0sdrw7h/3/

Comment: I see. But i need to set the overlay color based on data from my server. What then?

Comment: @standy So just pass it to the directive: https://jsfiddle.net/b0sdrw7h/5/

Comment: Great. Thank you!